# Record type missing for : Account; CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY : Minimum Access - Salesforce

Tags: profile, record-type, permission-sets

Use case is:

Integration user does REST API call to insert an Account without a RecordTypeId:

```
POST /services/data/v54.0/sobjects/Account 
{"Name" : "smoke-test"}
```

---

Integration User has ...

- Profile = `Minimum Access - Salesforce`
- Permission Set `MyIntegration`

  - Grants create/edit/view on `Account`
  - Assigns recordtype `B2B`
  - Run Flows enabled
- Before save flow coerces any Account record without RecordTypeId to the B2B recordtypeId

---

RESULT when API runs:

`Record type missing for : Account; CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY`

Debug log has no entries for traced integration user - not even the before save flow.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious things were checked

- Flow is active
- Permission set assigned
- CRUD access verified

The answer has to do with Profile `Minimum Access - Salesforce`

In the target org, the configuration for that profile for `Account` looked like this:

[image]

---

Note that there isn't even a default recordtype of `--Master--`

So, when the DML insert is done, SFDC checks to see if the running user has defined a default recordtype when none presented in the payload.  Since you can't define default recordtypes in Permission Sets and there's no default for the Profile `Minimum Access - Salesforce`, the insert fails almost immediately at the [beginning (probably step 2) of the Save process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

By changing the profile `Minimum Access - Salesforce` to at least have a default record type of `--Master--`, the record will save successfully

---

[image]